# Estimated time of update query of million rows (we're setting null to varbinary field)

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server production table with one million rows with varbinary field (each varbinary field contains file about 1-2 megabytes)

We have exported those files to file system, and now we're going to clean those field:

update table_name
set fileContentField = NULL

Questions:

1. What would be approximate execution time? Have no idea - 5 minutes, 5 hours or several days
2. Will the table be locked while script execution?
3. Is it recommended to update table with adding WHERE condition? and update by parts

Restrictions - we cant just remove the field, since it is required by backend scheme

Comment: One question per question please. And how would we have any idea about how long it will take in your database? Restore a backup and test all your ideas - that is the safest way to come up with a strategy for this.

Comment: got you, thanks. In our case test env has much less number of rows. Personally not a DBA, thats why asking

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly impossible to provide a 100% correct answer for all these very general questions because this depends on your setup. One point is e.g. if there are indexes and triggers on this table and if yes what they do.
A general idea to prevent poor update performance is like you've said updating by parts. If you don't have a specific condition to put in a where clause, you can create a loop and update just 10.000 (or any other amount you want) rows per update:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE fileContentField IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
UPDATE TOP (10000) yourtable 
SET fileContentField = NULL
END
```

But of course, you need to check your setup and if possible try out in a test environment. No one can tell you how long exactly such an update will take.